# Can I disable editing several forms by clicking one button

Tags: oracle-apex

I have several forms in Oracle ApEx and I need to disable editing them when a button on certain form is performed. By disable editing I mean remove edit, create and delete buttons and make all fields not enterable. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dynamic action on click of your button.

Add a Hide actions, and nominate the buttons you want to hide, also nominate your fields. You can identify multiple fields/buttons at once using jQuery selector.

Note, this is a client-side setting. You should also include validations to ensure relevant users aren't submitting data that doesn't match your intended business rule.

Comment: Thank you for your replay! I'm not good at js, now I'm trying to do it myself, but I may need later more help with it :)

Comment: The beauty of dynamic actions is that it removes most need for JS in typical interactions. You still need to understand Selectors, but the basic premise is they allow you to query the contents of your HTML.